# how to boot ubuntu from another disk

Tags: boot, 13.10, hard-drive, ssd

My senario is:
I have a desktop computer with two disk. One of disk is SSD and other is HDD. I install Windows 8 on SSD and I use HDD for data. Then I want to install ubuntu 13.10 on HDD with seperated partition on HDD and I install ubuntu 13.10 . Now my computer has Windows 8 on SSD and Ubuntu 13.10 on HDD. But when I change boot order (first bootable disk to HDD) to boot ubuntu from HDD, Ubuntu didn't start. How can I start the Ubuntu on HDD which already installed on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reinstall GRUB with [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). I think this will detect the Ubuntu installation and add make a menu to choose between Ubuntu or Windows.

Comment: Thanks this guide is worked. And I now writing from Ubuntu. :)

Answer (score 0):

As you installed Ubuntu after installing Windows 8, you shouldn't have to change the boot order in the BIOS. Ubuntu installs a bootloader (GRUB) which should see Windows 8 and add it to it's startmenu.

If you change the boot order to the HDD, it doesn't work because Grub is not installed on the HDD.

Doing a boot-repair as Wouter suggested is the best option to repair a lost bootloader.